# IPhone 5 not charging when idling

Tags: iphone, charge

my phone behavior is very strange. If I plug the charger in and do not use the phone, it not charging. It only can be charged if I using it. I've reset but it's still the same. Do you have any idea about it.

Thank you.

Comment: Based on what are you assuming that it does not charge while not being used? Did you restart your phone already to see if this changes anything?

Comment: The battery % is not increase, I even reset the phone

Comment: Your charger might be broke.

Comment: I hope it too but why it will start charging if I start using my phone :(

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it may have something to do with the charger cable connection. Before I realized there was lint in my phone's charger port, I was able to sometimes get it to charge when pulling horizontally on the cable.

Check out the phone's lighting port *and* the laptop's usb ports with a flashlight to see if there is any lint in there blocking the connection